# How can I install kernel modules on a mounted file system?

Tags: systemd, kernel-modules, embedded, yocto

I'm setting up an embedded system that is built using the Yocto project.  This outputs a root file system, kernel, u-boot, etc.  I have an installer script that I run from an SD card that configures the eMMC on the board with partitions, copies in the rootfs, uboot, etc.  It produces a bootable system when I boot from eMMC.

The problem I'm having is with the ethernet driver.  Is isn't installed on the system by default.  The installation script copies it to `/lib/modules/4.14.98-imx8mq+gea48c83/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/freescale/fec.ko` and I can log in over serial and manually load it with `insmod`, and that works fine.  But I'm not sure how to get it to load automatically.

Systemd looks in `/etc/modules-load.d/` for lists of modules to load, but this process seems to use modprobe and not insmod.  The modprobe system doesn't really know about the ethernet driver because I haven't run depmod on it.  But I can't run depmod from the installer because it would install it on my SD card installation, not on the eMMC.

What is my best approach here?  Do I need to find some way to run depmod during the installation?  Maybe it could be done with chroot?

Or is there a good way to get my module to load automatically without using the depmod/modprobe system?

Any insight here would be very appreciated.

Comment: At least my depmod has a `-b` option which avoids the need to use chroot.

Comment: So I would just do -b and point to the mounted /lib/modules/4.14.98-imx8mq+gea48c83 on the eMMC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User icarus was correct in their comment to my post.

I am issuing the following command from my installation script and that seems to be working:

```
depmod -b /mnt/root1 -a 4.14.98-imx8mq+gea48c83
```

The last argument is because the kernel version on the SD card system I'm booting from is different than the system I am modifying.